Trying to understand pygame.key.get_pressed()
I made the following toy code to understand what pygame.key.get_pressed() means
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys:
            print(keys, 'key pressed')

When I ran the code, it produced this output, in despite of any key was pressed or not
pygame.key.ScancodeWrapper(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False) key pressed

What happened? What is the purpose of using pygame.key.get_pressed() and when is it needed?

get_pressed() is for determining whether a particular key is being pressed at the moment, but you need to do a little work to make it useful.
From the get_pressed() documentation:

Returns a sequence of boolean values representing the state of every key on the keyboard. Use the key constant values to index the array. A True value means that the button is pressed.

So the output will be a sequence containing whether or not every single key on the keyboard is currently down.
That information isn't very useful on its own, but you can index it using the pygame keycodes to determine whether a particular key is being pressed.
For example, to continuously print whether the space key is currently down, you can use the following code:
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        print(keys[pygame.K_SPACE])


From the documentation:

Use the key constant values to index the array. A True value means that the button is pressed.

Also:

Note
Getting the list of pushed buttons with this function is not the proper way to handle text entry from the user. There is no way to know the order of keys pressed, and rapidly pushed keys can be completely unnoticed between two calls to pygame.key.get_pressed(). There is also no way to translate these pushed keys into a fully translated character value. See the pygame.KEYDOWN events on the pygame.eventpygame module for interacting with events and queues queue for this functionality.

